# how to change color on barplot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, visualization

I created a barplot using the function barplot() in R. The scripts are below:

```
nms <- rownames(ranef(Syn_Model_TM)$verb)
labels <- paste(nms)
png("verb_TM.png", width=10, height=6, units="in", res=300)
barplot(intercepts[order(intercepts)],names.arg=labels[order(intercepts)],horiz=FALSE, las=2, ylim=c(-3,3), cex.names=1)
dev.off()
```

And the plot is below:

[image]

Now, I was wondering if it is possible to change the color of the barplots such that the bars below 0 (y-axis) have different colors than the bars above 0. For instance, can I change the colors of all the bars with values < 0 to light grey, and the colors of all the bars with values >0 to dark grey or black? Thank you in advance for your help or comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
nms <- rownames(ranef(Syn_Model_TM)$verb)
labels <- paste(nms)
intercepts <- ranef(Syn_Model_TM)$verb[, "Intercept"]
colors <- ifelse(intercepts < 0, "lightgrey", "darkgrey")
png("verb_TM.png", width=10, height=6, units="in", res=300)
barplot(intercepts[order(intercepts)], names.arg=labels[order(intercepts)],
        horiz=FALSE, las=2, ylim=c(-3,3), cex.names=1, col=colors)
dev.off()
```